# The Cookie set is not detected

Tags: php, cookies

Hi guys i set a cookie using my script known as cookieset.php

```
setcookie("atid", $atid, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", ".mydomain.com");
```

and it is shown in the browser

```
Name    atid
Content 1234
```

but when i try to retrieve it like this from another script

```
echo 'value is: ' . $_COOKIE['atid'];
```

it gives the error saying

```
undefnied index: atid in.........
```

can anybody help me over this

Comment: Is it the same request?

Comment: You can not get coookie value first time you requested.

Comment: what do you mean by first time request

Answer (score 2):

```
setcookie("atid",$atid,time()+315360,"/");


// use

if (isset($_COOKIE['atid'])) {
    echo "cookeies set ";
} else {
    echo "cookeies not set ";
}
```

use mozila firebug / cookies to see cookies file

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: dou have mozila firbug ?? extantion

Comment: if you are using Google crome follow the step --> Right click > inspect element > resource > cookies > you domain ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem (from the error), seems to be that `$_COOKIE['atid']` (depending on what line the error is at) is undefined - that means it has not been set, and seeing that you actually set the cookie, I am saying that its the atid that is undefined. Make sure you are getting it, check with `isset()`

**Try this :**

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['atid'])) {
    echo $_COOKIE['atid'];
} else {
    echo "No cookie Set";
}
```

**And one more point :**

it won't be available until the `next page load or by doing the page request again`.

Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the `$_COOKIE` or `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The $_COOKIE array is populated with information sent from the browser. The first time you request the file that calls setcookie - cookieset.php - the server sends the cookie to the browser, but at this time the $_COOKIE array was already populated without the cookie you just set. 
The cookie will be available in subsequent requests until it expires.

To see the cookie in PHP, just do like this.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['atid'])) {
    echo 'Cookie found with value ' . $_COOKIE['atid'];
} else {
    setcookie('atid', $atid, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", ".mydomain.com");
    echo 'Cookie was set. Please refresh to see it working';
}
```

Comment: "Cookie was set. Please refresh to see it working" does not change... it appears on every time i refresh

Comment: I assume you've updated the domain name with your own!